# Context menu right click -- Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, contextmenu

Iam using Jquery Context menu in these way..,

```
function ApplyContextMenu() {
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.pnlAccordion h3',
    callback: function (key, options) {
        ContextMenuAction(key, options, $(this));
    },
    items: {
        "Add": { name: "Add Port", icon: "add" },
        "Edit": { name: "Edit Port", icon: "edit" },
    }

});
}
  function ContextMenuAction(key, options, $Port) {

           $(".dialogADD").dialog('open');
     if (key == "Add") {   
    $(".dialogADD").dialog({
        height: 238,
        width: 465,
        resizable: false,
        title: "Add Ports"

    });

       $(".imgbtnUpdateContext").click(function () {

           //Ajax Call Does action
            success: function (JSONData) {
                    try {
                         $(".dialogADD").dialog('close');
                        }
     }
         });
```

Here after many trials on this hide() and show() of dialog, i finally found that problem is not for hide() and show() of dialog, but its on Context Menu right click.

**PROBLEM:**

When i hit right click as "ADD" for the first time its inserting one record
when i hit it second time its inserting two times the same record, third time 3 times the same record.

Here actually for the second time even if i do not hit update button its entering into it,

problem is on the right click, Its counting number of clicks on the right click and entering into Update button,
How should i restrict it into entering into Update click for the second time / third time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**event.preventDefault()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), which on called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Also bind your click event using `.on('click', function())` handler

```
$(".imgbtnUpdateContext").on('click', function (e) {    
    //Ajax Call Does action
    success: function (JSONData) {
        try {
            $(".dialogADD").dialog('close');
        }
    }        
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Updates:**

```
$(".imgbtnUpdateContext").unbind("click").click(function () {
    //Ajax Call Does action
    success: function (JSONData) {
        try {
            $(".dialogADD").dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @þÍńķ Instead of `e.preventDefault()` try using `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Comment: I dont understand prob but still clicking it second time is giving 2 inserts......

Comment: @þÍńķ possible to make a fiddle?

Comment: `$(".imgbtnUpdateContext").on('click', function (e) {    
    //Ajax Call Does action
    success: function (JSONData) {
        try {
            $(".dialogADD").dialog('close');e.stopImmediatePropagation()
        }
    }        
});`

Comment: Ok will try.., This is real time scenerio.., try to make a fiddle

Comment: I can't make fiddle, because you're using ajax.  Also would like you to try this`$(".imgbtnUpdateContext").unbind("click").click(function () {`.  Unbinding and then attaching click handler.

Comment: Ok will try.., i was struck here.., trying all my ways...,

Comment: In unbind what do u want me to do?

Comment: `$(".imgbtnUpdateContext")$(".imgbtnUpdateContext").unbind("click").click(function () {

           //Ajax Call Does action
            success: function (JSONData) {
                    try {
                         $(".dialogADD").dialog('close');
                        }
     }
         });`

Comment: i used it these way  $(".imgbtnUpdateContext").unbind("click").click(function () {

this is working.., I mean not hitting second time..,

Comment: "not hitting second time" means unable to click next time?

Comment: No iam able to click, my problem is solved.., previously if i hit it second time 2 records where inserted now only one record is getting inserted

Comment: @þÍńķ Oh that's great.  I will include this in my answer.